# Find the highest number inside a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to find the highest number inside a string from a file. For example, in the file `password.txt` we have:

```
 jaime:45:/home/jaime:/bin/bash
 sofia:113:/home/sofia:/bin/bash
 marta:2015:/home/marta:/bin/bash
 pedro:2024:/home/pedro:/bin/bash
```

So the highest number should be `2024` and we have to save it into a variable:-

```
number=2024
```

I've tried several things with `grep`, `awk`, `sed` or even with `sort`, but without any solution.

Comment: It would be good, if you can share your efforts and let us know how it failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest:

```
number=$(cut -d: -f 2 file | sort -n | tail -n 1)
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but suggesting multiple tools for this trivial task is bit of an over-kill

Comment: this is the best answer of all. it's a false statement to say it `suggesting multiple tools`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: It is a perfectly valid answer, why invoke three processes when you can do with one in `awk`? does that not mean multiple usage? Imagine a case when the input scales for a million line file? Which one do you think will perform faster?

Comment: @Inian if you consider performance, which one do you think faster, a shell script using general tools, or a specialized c program? the goal of a shell script is to deliver a concise and high level combination of tools, regardless other considerations appear to be most of the time trivial, including the number of processes and performance. if you are worried about these two, shell is not the right tool to start with. otherwise, this is the best solution which excludes the unnecessary explicit tiny logic within awk.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: If we are limiting this discussion only within the  scope of `shell` to process file, I am betting this surely will scale slower than the other two `awk` answers here.

Answer (score 2):

*`Awk`* to the rescue!

```
awk -F":" 'BEGIN{max=0}{if(($2)>max)  max=$2}END {print max}' file
2024
```

To save it in a variable,

```
max="$( awk -F":" 'BEGIN{max=0}{if(($2)>max)  max=$2}END {print max}' file)"
printf "%d\n" "$max"
2024
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
number=$(grep -o '[0-9]*' password.txt | sort -nr | head -1)
```

Comment: What happens if there is a line such as `sofia9999:113:/home/sofia:/bin/bash` in the file?

Comment: thats the catch, but thats not in the provided input.

Comment: @FarhadFarahi; That could be a valid line in the input

Answer (score 1):

@Thotensar: If your Input_file is same as shown as sample Input, then following may help you in same.

```
awk -F":" '{Q=Q>$2?Q:$2} END{print Q}'  Input_file
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Fahrad his answer gives me the expected result in some other context of finding the highest amount of a range of amounts, in order to use it for percentage calculation afterwards:

```
cat $(dirname "$0")/wordcount.txt | xargs -n 1 | sort -g | uniq -c | paste -s --delimiters=";" | tr -s ' ' 'x' | sed 's/;x/; /g' | sed 's/x/ x /g' | cut -c 4- > $(dirname "$0")/wordcount_temp.txt

RESULT=$(cat $(dirname "$0")/wordcount_temp.txt)

echo "$RESULT"

echo

MAXIMUM=$(grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,} x' $(dirname "$0")/wordcount_temp.txt | sort -nr | head -1 | sed 's/ x//g')

echo "$MAXIMUM"
```

Gives:

12 x 0; 14 x 1; 17 x 2; 7 x 3; 3 x 4; 8 x 5; 11 x 6; 18 x 7; 9 x 8; 13 x 9

18

Thank you.